# Добавить кодом Source для Image с помощью .resx в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

Я кодом создал новый Image в WPF:

```
var body = new Image();
```

и, допустим, имеется файл ресурса, т.е. resx-файл изображения.
Как мне задать свойство

```
body.Source = ???
```

Это я хочу написать прямо в коде, а не в XAML

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062221/images-bound-to-images-added-to-resx-files-using-xaml

Comment: Я бы хотел написать это кодом на c#, или это невозможно?

Comment: возможно, но зачем?

Comment: Потому что я создаю их динамически во время программы, а на исходной форме у меня вообще отсутствуют Image-ы

Comment: в чем проблема сделать кодом?

Comment: Я не знаю, как это написать кодом

Comment: ...что конкретно вы не знаете? какой свойство отвечает за изображение? читайте разметку - `Source`. как сконвертировать в формат доступный для `Image`? читайте ответ по ссылке, там указано откуда можно взять код для [конвертера](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap), вы вместо конвертера можете написать функцию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В проект, в котором будет находиться класс `PictureConverter` нужно добавить ссылку на библиотеку `System.Drawing`.

Добавляется так: выбираем в проекте курсором мыши `References`, жмём правую кнопку мыши, выбираем пункт `Add Reference`, там находим библиотеку `System.Drawing` и ставим галочку.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546091/wpf-createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap-memory-leak/7035036#7035036

**GdiNativeMethods.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// FxCop requires all Marshalled functions to be in a class called NativeMethods.
    /// </summary>
    internal static class GdiNativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
    }
}
```

**PictureConverter.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public static class PictureConverter
    {
        public static BitmapSource ConvertToBitmapSource(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                handle = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
                return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                   handle,
                   IntPtr.Zero,
                   Int32Rect.Empty,
                   BitmapSizeOptions.FromWidthAndHeight(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
            }
            finally
            {
                if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    GdiNativeMethods.DeleteObject(handle);
                }
            }
        }

        public static BitmapSource ConvertToBitmapImage(Bitmap bitmap)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
                memory.Position = 0;
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
                bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapImage.EndInit();

                return bitmapImage;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using Image = System.Windows.Controls.Image;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = PictureConverter.ConvertToBitmapSource(Properties.Resources._111);
            rootGrid.Children.Add(image);
        }
    }
}
```

Решил я затестить вариант преобразования вот таким методом:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            // Вызовем по одному разу, чтобы JIT скопилировал код
            PictureConverter.ConvertToBitmapImage(WpfApp1.Properties.Resources._111);
            PictureConverter.ConvertToBitmapSource(WpfApp1.Properties.Resources._111);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            const int Iterations = 100;
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
            {
                PictureConverter.ConvertToBitmapImage(WpfApp1.Properties.Resources._111);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            sb.AppendFormat("ConvertToBitmapImage.ElapsedTicks: {1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, sw.ElapsedTicks);

            sw.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++)
            {
                PictureConverter.ConvertToBitmapSource(WpfApp1.Properties.Resources._111);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            sb.AppendFormat("ConvertToBitmapSource.ElapsedTicks: {1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, sw.ElapsedTicks);

            string result = sb.ToString();
            Debug.Write(result);
        }
    }
}
```

И получил результаты:

- `ConvertToBitmapImage.ElapsedTicks:` **9919067**
- `ConvertToBitmapSource.ElapsedTicks:` **2498690**

Comment: Спасибо за конвертер

Comment: Вот взяли и сделали все за автора вопроса ;)

Comment: Ev_Hyper, да тут просто дело в том, что кто-то в будущем будет искать ответ и неважно, что я сделал за автора, кому-то ещё поможет мой ответ, я надеюсь.